# Invalid credentials in Drive API with php

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to do a simple list (in php) of all the files that a user have in his drive. I wanna save the access token, user id and email in bd and to get the user id and email I wrote this code:

```
(..)
$api=new Google_Client();
$api->setAccessToken($accessToken);
$api->setUseObjects(true);
$userInfoService = new Google_Oauth2Service($api);
$userinfo=$userInfoService->userinfo->get();
(..)
```

In the last line of this sample I get this error:

Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo: (401) Invalid Credentials

but I print the accessToken that I send and it's correct.

Comment: It's not an access token that has expired because I do this after I get the access token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access tokens expire after one hour. Perhaps you are trying to reuse an access token that has expired?

Check the DrEdit application for a complete PHP sample showing how to properly store credentials in a db and restore them when needed:

https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/php

Comment: It's not an access token that has expired because I do this right after I get the access token.

Comment: I was forgeting some scopes that's why it was falling. Thanks for the link.